# How to redirect a URL wildcard using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My site was hacked not too long ago and a lot of URLs were created in the following format:

```
http://example.com/prematurely.asp?skin=pspfsffdproblems=nq....
```

is there anyway I can re-direct all these wildcard URLs based on prematurely.asp to a single page? for example:

```
http://example.com/newpage
```

.htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nowcosmetic\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nowcosmetic.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/questions-and-answers\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://nowcosmetic.co.uk/botox.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^prematurely\.asp /botox? [R=301,L]'
```

Comment: If these URLs were the result of a hack (which has now been cleaned up) and now no longer exist then you are better off just letting these URLs fail with a 404 (or 410) rather than redirecting. A redirect would send the wrong message to search engines.

Comment: I think this will solve your problem 

    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /prematurely\.asp\?skin=([^=]+)=([^\s]+) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/newpage? [NE,NC,R,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^prematurely/(.*)   /newpage [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The `(.*)` at the end of the `RewriteRule` pattern is superfluous, but also the OP is wanting to match "prematurely.asp", not "prematurely/". This will also pass the query string onto the target URL which is probably not desirable - you need a trailing `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution to omit this.

Comment: Tried Ron's suggestion, but it still goes to a 404. http://nowcosmetic.co.uk/prematurely.asp?skin=DdfNJ&problems=RV_lP&page=253079

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, if these URLs are the result of a hacked site which has now been resolved then you are better off (SEO wise) serving a 404 (or 410 Gone) instead of redirecting.

However, if you still want to redirect...

> re-direct all these wildcard URLs based on **prematurely.asp** to a single page

At the top of your .htaccess file (in your document root):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^prematurely\.asp /newpage? [R=301,L]
```

Note that `RewriteEngine On` should only appear once in your file (at the top).

This simply matches against "prematurely.asp" (ignoring the query string - as per your request). The trailing `?` on the `RewriteRule` substitution strips the original query string from the rewritten URL.

Comment: Hi. Still no joy. I've added my htaccess here:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nowcosmetic\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nowcosmetic.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/questions-and-answers\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://nowcosmetic.co.uk/botox.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^prematurely\.asp /botox? [R=301,L]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code there - it will be much easier to read and retain its formatting. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the htaccess code.

Comment: You have a stray `'` at the end of the last statement - but I assume that's just a typo in the question? There would seem to be "something else" going on here - as the behaviour is not consistent with the directives in the .htaccess file. If you navigate to `/prematurely.asp` then you are redirected to `/botox`, however, `/prematurely.asp-something` is not redirected, when it should be (according to the above directives). Now, if you navigate to `/botox.html` then it redirects to `/botox` - where is it doing that? That's not controlled by .htaccess?

Comment: Ideally, the directive above should go immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive, however, it would not seem to matter too much in this instance, as the other directives do not appear to conflict.

Comment: Hi. I'm using Artio JoomSef to handle the other URL issues.